# Ninject: Dynamically loading modules in Silverlight

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

The reason I want to load modules dynamically is to avoid circular dependency issue. I have following layers View --> ViewModel --> DataProvider --> ServiceClient (wcf proxies).

Now I want a static IoC container that can be shared across these layers. I want to make my View testable and to do that I’ll have to inject the various dependencies in various layers and mock out those dependencies as well. Now issue I am facing is where to declare and load ninject modules.

i also realised in Silverlight version of Ninject there is no version of Load which take string arugment, which can be used to load the modules dynamically Load("*.dll"). How can I achieve dynamic loading in Silverlight

Thanks

Comment: The overload of `Load` that walks the currently loaded assemblies in the AppDomain might be appropriate. BTW this really is a question for the Ninject mailing list. You'll likely get a better answer there.

Comment: that overload is not available in silverlight either

Comment: BTW worth looking at a few xap MEF tutorials to give an idea of the lie of the land

Answer (score 1):

In silverlight you have to deploy everithing in an xap. Therefore there is nothing like dynamically loading assemblies. It is simpy not supported by the silverlight framework.